# Reuse xaml UserControl with viewmodels in Caliburn Micro

Tags: xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In my wpf app i use Caliburn Micro. Now i created a UserControl called VariableView.xaml. Caliburn Micro will look for the corresponding VariableViewModel.cs. No problem here.
The VariableViewModel class has three properties that are used by the view to bound to: VariableName, VariableValue and VariableUnit. For example for temperature they are set to "Temperature", "40.5" and "°C".

In my MainViewModel.cs i use the VariableViewModel three times.

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  public VariableViewModel TempatureViewModel{get;}
  public VariableViewModel PressureViewModel{get;}
  public VariableViewModel HumidityViewModel{get;}
 
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    TemperatureViewModel = new VariableViewModel("Temperature", "°C", "40.5");
    ...
  }
}
```

The values are shown in the views.
What i would like to do is derive a class from VariableViewModel named TemperatureVariableViewModel which automatically sets the VariableName, VariableUnits and VariableValue in the constructor like:

```
public class TemperatureVariableViewModel : VariableViewModel
{
   public TemperatureVariableViewModel()
      : base("Temperature", "°C", "40.5")
   {

   }
}
```

Replacing the VariableViewModel type in the MainViewModel with the TemperatureViewModel type creates a problem.
The problem now is that the view is not displayed. Probably Caliburn Micro can not find the corresponding viewmodel for the view anymore. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using custom logic for `ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType`, which helps identify View for ViewModels.
For example, You could begin by creating an attribute `UseViewOf` (approach without attribute is also explained below)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class,AllowMultiple =false)]
public class UseViewOfAttribute:Attribute
{
  public Type SelectedType { get; set; }
  public UseViewOfAttribute(Type type) => SelectedType = type;
}
```

You could now decorate your derived class with the attribute

```
[UseViewOf(typeof(VariableViewModel))]
public class TemperatureVariableViewModel: VariableViewModel
{
```

And now finally in your `Bootstrap` class, you could override the `ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType` with your own custom logic as following

```
var existingViewLocator = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType;

ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
            {
                var targetType = existingViewLocator(modelType, displayLocation, context);

                if(targetType == null && modelType.GetCustomAttributes<UseViewOfAttribute>().Any())
                {
                    var attribute = modelType.GetCustomAttribute<UseViewOfAttribute>();
                    targetType = existingViewLocator(attribute.SelectedType,displayLocation,context);
                }

                return targetType;
            };
```

If you do not want to use the Attrbibute, you could change the custom logic to retrieve the View for the Parent Class. For example,

```
var existingViewLocator = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType;
ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
            {
                var targetType = existingViewLocator(modelType, displayLocation, context);

                if(targetType == null)
                {
                    while(targetType == null)
                    {
                        modelType = modelType.BaseType;
                        targetType = existingViewLocator(modelType, displayLocation, context);
                    }
                }

                return targetType;
            };
```

I would prefer the Attribute approach as it makes code more readable (future developer could easily understand which View would be used for the viewmodel).

Comment: Pls help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71813298/5777453

Comment: This solution works great! For my 3 viewmodels TemperatureVariableViewModel, PressureVariableViewModel and HumidityVariableViewModel the same VariableView is shown. As a sidenote i would like to add that the TemperatureVariableView, PressureVariableView and HumidityVariableView classes should be removed in order for above mentioned view locator to work. Otherwise it would still show the custom implementation instead of the base view.